# Why is my row not updating?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've created a Prepared Statement that should be updating a row, however, the row does not update.

```
    /**
 * Sets the last modified date of the Index to Now();
 * Automatically gets the number of files and total size of files in index that are included in the index and sets that data too.
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws UnexpectedException 
 */
public void MarkUpdated() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, UnexpectedException
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement1 = null;
    PreparedStatement statement2 = null;
    PreparedStatement statement3 = null;
    ResultSet rSet1 = null;
    ResultSet rSet2 = null;
    // First, lets obtain the file count
    try
    {
    Integer count;
    connection = ConnectionMgr.getConnectionToSc1();
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    statement1 = connection.prepareStatement
            ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM indexFiles WHERE IndexID=? AND IndexUUID=?");
    statement1.setLong(1, IndexID);
    statement1.setString(2, IndexUUID);
    rSet1 = statement1.executeQuery();
    if (rSet1.next())
    {

        count = rSet1.getInt(1);

    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnexpectedException("Failed to Mark Updated - Couldn't get file count?");
    }
    // Now lets obtain the total amount of disk space these files are occupying
    // This is a bit more complicated
    Long size;
    statement2 = connection.prepareStatement
            ("SELECT SUM(FileSize) FROM files WHERE FileUUID IN "
            +"(SELECT FileUUID FROM indexFiles WHERE IndexID=? AND IndexUUID=?)");
    statement2.setLong(1, IndexID);
    statement2.setString(2, IndexUUID);
    rSet2 = statement2.executeQuery();
    if (rSet2.next())
    {
        size = rSet2.getLong(1);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnexpectedException("Failed to Mark Updated - Couldn't get sum of file sizes?");
    }




    // Now we mark the index as updated with the new file count
    statement3 = connection.prepareStatement
            ("UPDATE indexes SET FileCount=? AND Size=? WHERE IndexID=? AND IndexUUID=?");
    statement3.setInt(1, count);
    statement3.setLong(2, size);
    statement3.setLong(3, IndexID);
    statement3.setString(4, IndexUUID);
    //if (1 != 0)
    //{
    //  throw new UnexpectedException("Count " + count + " Size " + size + " IndexID " + IndexID + " IndexUUID " + IndexUUID);
    //}
    int rowsUpdated = statement3.executeUpdate();
    if (rowsUpdated != 1) {throw new UnexpectedException("Failed to mark an index as updated: Index UUID is " + IndexUUID);}
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(rSet1);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(rSet2);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(statement1);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(statement2);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(statement3);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
    }
}
```

Purposely thrown exception
[Purposely thrown exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4m14.png)

You can see from my debug code I tried throwing an exception to see that everything is set correctly. I can confirm that a row with this IndexID/UUID exists in my table.

The statement is executed and no exception is thrown indicating that an update occured - however, when checking my table, these values are not updated.

I'm trying to figure out why that might be? I have checked and I have not set autocommit to false when constructing my connection. The columns FileCount and Size are both set to default '0' - but default values should not override statement values, right?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Could autocommit be false __by default__?

Comment: Are you performing a **connection.commit()** ?

Also, are the statements, connections **closed()** properly ?

Comment: I tried explicitly setting autocommit to true in my code just before the statement to true to see just now - The row did not update. I doubt it is that anyway as I also create connections elsewhere in my application to perform updates on other tables which work just fine. I was able to set an arbitrary value via mysql workbench however?

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as text in your question. Do not use images. And make sure it includes the actual MySQL exception and not some random exception your own program throws.

Comment: I updated to show the full method - I'm pretty sure i'm closing everything right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as if your update syntax is wrong, the first AND should be a comma:

```
UPDATE indexes SET FileCount=?, Size=? WHERE IndexID=? AND IndexUUID=?
```

Try that.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Another time, if you have a problem like this, I'd suggest you check the SQL syntax in MySQL Workbench or wherever before you start trying to debug the code (obvs you would need to put real values in place of the ?s when checking the syntax)